# SQL Server - remove HTML Tag from a varchar

Tags: sql-server

I know there are a few about similar topics on here but I can't find one related to my issue, this is it:

I have a table with an ID Column and a QRCode column. each time an item is added the primary key auto increments. The QRCode will scan in to be like the following:

"http://somewebsite.com/12345/987654321"

i want to be able to remove the "http://somewebsite.com/" from the string, I know how to do this in C# however I am unsure of how to do this in Sql Server. any guidance would be great, thanks

Regular formats are like the following, and used in the example below.

```
"http://somewebsite.com/12345/456564654"
"http://somewebsite.com/12345/989886765"
"http://somewebsite.com/12346/987654321"
```

the query returns the following results:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE
(
    REPLACE(QRCode, 'http://somewebsite.com/', '')
    ,'/', ' '
) AS QRCode
FROM 
QRTable 
WHERE 
QRCode LIKE '%http://somewebsite.com/%'
```

"12345 456564654"
"12345 989886765"
"12346 987654321"

Now i need to update the table with those new results however as there's 3 results, i get the error message "Subquery returned more than 1 value". is there a way to replace the selected values in the table with the ones that exist based on the primary key field?

Comment: Can you give some more examples for the `QRCode`field? Will it be in a regular format (like _url/numbers/numbers_)?

Comment: SELECT * is generally bad practice as well might want to explicitly select your columns.

Comment: Whats your update statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Removed previous example

A more complete answer based on your updated question. This removes the first portion of the URL as well as the trailing `/` so that you get your desired output.

```
DECLARE @Variable VARCHAR(50)
SET @Variable = 'http://somewebsite.com/12345/456564654'
SET @Variable =
    REPLACE
    (
        REPLACE(@Variable, 'http://somewebsite.com/', '')
        ,'/', ' '
    )
PRINT @Variable
```

Output = 12345 456564654

Looking at your SQL statement you want this:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE
    (
        REPLACE(QRCode, 'http://somewebsite.com/', '')
        ,'/', ' '
    ) AS QRCode
FROM 
    QRTable 
WHERE 
    QRCode LIKE '%http://somewebsite.com/%'
```

Comment: but how do i detect the "http://somewebsite.com/" part in the string so it doesnt rename all the values in the column?

Comment: Perhaps, in the case, a better example would be: `select replace(QRCode, 'http://somewebsite.com/', '') as LocalPath, otherColumn from theTable where condition`. Also worth noting [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) does not replace the whole string: its like `String.Replace`.

Comment: But is it always somewebsite.com/ or can it also be anotherwebsite.com? Because then this won't work.

Comment: According to their question it is or at least given that impression. Clearly the example above doesn't deal with different URLs to be replaced but then the OP hasn't requested it..

Comment: always somewebsite.... although making it generic so between 'http' and the final / would be great if that is possible.

and the above answer returns this error when i try and SET the variable: Must declare the scalar variable "@Varaible".

Comment: Have you delcared the variable? As in copied the entire statement. Seems like you haven't. You need that line which DECLARE @Variable

Comment: doesnt work when there is more than one value that matches the select statement when updating... any ideas how to solve that

Comment: Can you give an example? As in the values you are working with>